# Does FirebaseAuth idTokenChanges Stream notify when idToken expires?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am looking at the API for FirebaseAuth for flutter.

It provides the following function...

```
  /// Notifies about changes to the user's sign-in state (such as sign-in or
  /// sign-out) and also token refresh events.
  Stream<User?> idTokenChanges() =>
      _pipeStreamChanges(_delegate.idTokenChanges());
```

I am curious if this Stream will also update when the current idToken expires.

Answer (score 0):

The `onIdTokenChanged` event fires when the app gets a new ID token or fails to get a new ID token. From the documentation on [onIdTokenChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged):

> Adds an observer for changes to the signed-in user's ID token, which includes sign-in, sign-out, and token refresh events.

So:

- If the user signs in and gets their first ID token, the `onIdTokenChanged` fires with that token.
- When the ID token refreshes (usually every hour), the `onIdTokenChanged` fires with the new token.
- When the ID token refresh fails, the `onIdTokenChanged` fires with no token.
- When the user actively signs out, the `onIdTokenChanged` fires with no token.

So it doesn't really fire when the current token expires, as much as when the app gets (or fails to get) a new token.